# Overlapping child element with parent for menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a window blind effect menu for a mobile project. The effect is simple and goes as follow :

1. Click on the menu icon and the bar goes to the top with the menu dropping down
2. When selecting an item, the menu "rolls" up in a window blind fashion and the content appears in the same fashion

Here are the bits of CSS that I think is the culprit :

```
#menu_wrapper ul {
display: none;
top: 100px;
right: 0;
bottom: auto;
left: auto;
position: absolute;
height: auto;
width: 100vw;
margin: 0;
padding: 1em;
color: #f5f5f5;
font-size: 2.5rem;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); }

#menu_wrapper ul a {
color: #f5f5f5; }

#menu_wrapper ul a:hover {
color: #00a8b0;
text-decoration: none; }

#menu_wrapper address {
margin-top: 1.5rem;
font-size: 1.5rem; }


#menu_wrapper .item-content {
display: none;
top: 50%;
right: 0;
bottom: auto;
left: auto;
position: absolute;
height: auto;
width: 100vw;
margin: 0;
padding: 1em;
z-index: 3; }
```

The problem is that the "item-content" stay inside the parent "menu_wrapper". It might have something to do with the fact that "menu_wrapper" is absolutely positioned but I'm still having trouble with those peculiar cases. It might also be my jQuery code but I doubt it (suggestions are still welcomed)!

I've included a link to a jsFiddle for you to look at : http://jsfiddle.net/smpte11/5s6qxntt/

Thanks.

EDIT : I want to precise the effect that I'm trying to achieve. When clicking on the menu, it drops down and when I close the menu, it goes up until it disappears in a window blind fashion. Now, when I click on one item of the menu, the menu rolls up until it disappears (like when you close it) and then the content goes down, revealing it instead of the menu. Naturally, when you go to the previous level, the same effects happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is that you want it to look like - I've just adjusted your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewq83Lzt/) with following changes:

CSS:

```
 #menu_wrapper .item-content {
   position:relative;
 }
```

so each submenu is displayed next to the submenu headline.

jQuery:

```
function showPageContentPhone() {
 menu.on('click', 'li:not(:last-child) a', function () {
    console.log("click");
    var that = $(this);
    that.next('div').slideToggle();

  });
}
```

Previously the main navigation initially slided up everytime a submenu item was clicked, now the submenus just behave as submenus (but maybe the previous effect was intended).

Comment: Thanks but it's not exactly what I'm seeking. I thought about the solution but I didn't like the effect. I will edit my question to reflect more precisely what I'm looking for! Thanks anyway!